# Recovering data from partially formatted external HDD

Tags: external-hard-drive, data-recovery

I had a 1 TB western digital external hard disk filled with data. Mistaking it for another USB drive, my friend right clicked and went ahead with formatting. Within around five seconds after the formatting began, I cancelled the process and removed the USB connection. I re inserted the hard disk afterwards, only to see that drive is not assigned any letter by PC, and it asks to be formatted, if I try to open. I tried accessing with Linux also, but to no avail. whats is my best way ahead to recover the data? how much of the data might have got formatted? Is there any way I could access the data that haven't been formatted from the disk, and then go for recovering the remaining formatted data, instead of going for recovery of the entire 1 TB using some tool?

Comment: If he used quick format, most should be recoverable. If he used regular format then a large chunk will have been zero'd. Use TestDisk or Photorec to scan the disk and recover all files, make sure you have 1TB of free space on the receiving disk.

Answer (score 0):

Recovering data from damaged or formatted hard drives can be tricky, but since it been only 5 seconds I guess you can recover most of the data in it. Try using [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), I have not tested this tool myself but according to my searches it can help a lot and can do a lots of things. You can also try [Piriform Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva), which is very popular tool for such things too.

There are a number of paid solutions like [R-Studio](http://www.r-studio.com/) but if they will be really effective it is not something I can assure you.

Oh, and **be sure that you must not write any information in the disk! Or you can end up having your data overwritten and lost forever**.

Comment: I have had great luck with Priform Recuva myself.   I do not work for or have any relationship with the company that makes Priform Recuva, this is just from personal experience.